# originalEvent.srcElement.closest not working in IE Angular

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, closest

Angular application with the following code is not working.

Angular code, trying to access the `td` of grid where the user clicks button from. It required the following code:

```
originalEvent.srcElement.closest("td")
```

The code is working fine in Chrome, but not in IE.

Can someone suggest me an alternative to this?

Comment: Just add a polyfill for it, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-closest

Comment: Added the polyfill and it worked